# Generate Matrix with Pairwise Distance of a Rectangle Grid -MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have rectangle `Rec`, size `M` units and `N` units. So I can make a grid which has `MN` small squares. Then, I indices them as a matrix indexing like the first row grids `# 1,2,...N` as `(1,1) (1,2), ... (1,N)` and the second row grids `# N+1,N+2,...2N` as `(2,1) (2,2), ... (2,N)` etc.

Now I want to generate matrix `Dis` size `MN x MN` which includes pairwise distance between any two points, i.e., `Dis` is a symmetric matrix with all-zero diagonal.

E.g., for rectangle `Rec`, size `5x6`, the distance between `Rec(2,3)` and `Rec(5,4)` (or `9th` and `22nd` grids) is `Rec(9,22)=Rec(22,9)=sqrt((2-5)^2+(3-4)^2)`.

Does any one know how to generate `Rec` efficiently with MATLAB?

Comment: By 'efficient' do you mean fast, or memory-efficient, or elegant to read? Have you already tried something and if so what was the problem with it?

Comment: Generate `Rec` as in structuring the data in the format you need?

Comment: If `Rec(2,3)` is the `9th` element it means that you define your linear index column-wise. But matlab use a row-wise linear index.

Comment: But you can simply generate all the combination with `[x1,x2,y1,y2] = ndgrid(1:m,1:n,1:m,1:n);`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it in row-wise linear index. I finally need only the correct distances.